# Get Azure Application ID from Enterprise Application Name in python

Tags: python, azure

I have an Azure Application name and I would like to know if there is a way to get the application ID of the enterprise application in python.

I am able to authenticate myself by passing in the clientID/ApplicationID and secret. But, I would like to know if there is a way to fetch client id/application ID using Azure Application name, so that I dont have to hardcode it.

Comment: Could you add the code with the error you are facing?

Comment: Basically, I have no clue as to how to do it. I have the code to authenticate using client id and secret. But I am trying to see if there is a way to fetch client id from a application name rather than hard-coding the client id directly in code itself

Comment: To authenticate you have to generate the access token and hence you have to pass clientid and secret manually

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that: To authenticate you need to pass `ClientID` and `ClientSecret`. To get the `ClientID` using Azure Application name also you need to authenticate by using `ClientID` and hence it is not feasible in python.

- Microsoft Entra ID application names are not unique hence it might create confusion to identify the application too.

**Alternatively**, you can make use of [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) explorer to get the **Enterprise application** `ClientID` and `ObjectID`:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$search="displayName:AppName"

ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

[image]

To get the **Microsoft Entra ID application** `ClientID` and `ObjectID`:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$search="displayName:AppName"

ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

[image]